# How to get Square root of a number without import anything in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import, math.sqrt

How to get Square root of a number without import anything in python?
You know we can do this:

```
import math
a = 4
s = math.sqrt(a)
```

but i want do this more simple without import any library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using Exponentiation in python line this:

```
a = 4
b = a ** 0.5    #(1/2)
```